# Comedy manhua about a girl who finds herself in a boy's body after an accident

Tags: story-identification, manga

I really forgot this masterpiece comic I once read. TnT
I think it was a manhua (Chinese), and the story goes:
A young, beautiful, perfect, sole daughter gets into an accident, then survives, but is now in a boy's body. So she still has her female consciousness, but in a male body. Then follows a series of really fun comedy scenes. I forgot the title, the character's names, and some details. Oh, her body was preserved too, but it's not sci fi? The title probably includes the term 'genderswap' or 'switch bodies'. Help, please.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, what colour was the main character's hair?

Comment: Welcome Suban. Can you recall what year you read it, was it new then? Was it in a comic book with other stories, or alone? Our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) might help jog your memory to give us some more details.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I actually just found it :0 like rn

Comment: Uhuh. It was a comic book. And I remember it was on Webcomics and then I found it XD yayy It's called Handsome and Cute

Comment: @Suban - Glad you found it. :-) Please feel free to submit a formal answer yourself, using the 'Your Answer' field below. You could earn some [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) from upvotes, and you'll be able to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 48 hours after the question was first posted.